# Get parent user control from control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, controls

I have a user control that contains a nested class (for a dynamic template in a grid), and in this nested class I have an event in which I want to call methods on my user control.

However, I am unable to do so as I don't know how to get a reference to my user control from this method. I have tried the following (where 'applications' is the name of my user control):

```
    void tp_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Applications app = (Applications)((Control)sender).Page;
    }
```

However this does not work as the user control obviously doesn't inherit from System.Web.UI.Page . Is there any I can get to the user control from one of the controls?

Comment: To me this design feels a little foreign, like winforms more than web.

Comment: Sounds like you need to research the `FindControl("Your UserControl Name")` method

Answer (score 0):

Add a constructor to the nested class that takes in a reference to the control. Save it in a private variable then voila you have access to the control....